# Why do i get a signature over the certificate in my soap header

Tags: c#, wcf-security, wcf-client, digital-signature

I need to communicate with a soap service that supports Soap1.1 en WS Security 1.0.
I have put up some code in C# that communicates with this service, but it's returning an FaultException.
One of the requirements from the serive is that I sign the soap body. The error I get back seems to be related with he signing of the message.

When I inspect the message that is sent to the service I can see there is a signature in it, but this signature has two references. The first (URI=#_2) is to the body, the second (URI=#uuid-67....) is to the certificate that is used to sign the message.

I expect this is causing the error. Can somebady please explain to me why this second reference is added to the signature and how I can get rid of it?

Source:

```
 //start communication
 EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(
 new Uri("https://klac.procesinfrastructuur.nl:443/PIAanleverservices/services/AanleverService"),
 EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("*.procesinfrastructuur.nl"));

 CustomBinding cbinding = new CustomBinding();
 var sec = (AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement)SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement(MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10);
 sec.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(new X509SecurityTokenParameters());
 sec.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10;
 sec.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
 sec.MessageProtectionOrder = MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncrypt; 
 sec.IncludeTimestamp = false;
 cbinding.Elements.Add(sec);

 var tme = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8);
 cbinding.Elements.Add(tme);

 var https = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
 https.RequireClientCertificate = true;
 cbinding.Elements.Add(https);

 ChannelFactory<AanleverService> factory = new ChannelFactory<AanleverService>(cbinding, address);
 factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new PaulsBehaviour());
 factory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My,
     X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "My Certificate");

 factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
                                              StoreName.My,
                                              X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                                              "*.procesinfrastructuur.nl");

 AanleverService client = factory.CreateChannel();
 try
 {
     leverAanRequest request = new leverAanRequest("", "KLogiO.OB20100305", "Omzetbelasting", "inhoud", //EncodeTo64(inhoudsigned),
                                               DateTime.Now, "24140938B01", "http://geenausp.nl");
     leverAanResponse resultaat = client.leverAan(request);
     Console.WriteLine("Resultaat: {0}/{1}", resultaat.leverAanReturn.PI_Kenmerk, resultaat.leverAanReturn.tijdstempelOntvangst);
     Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

Message:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <ActivityId CorrelationId="7b88bb7b-eb91-47c9-8163-8d0eb90e3adb" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">412197d8-e97b-4e33-a988-1a5390b798a4</ActivityId>
    <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo44bS9QvZcdJjhUDKzWRBs8AAAAAeNyqcH1zhkeOzSiaDD0CyM+e8mGeN1FCmpSR5zqYPf8ACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-582a2846-2291-4c45-b788-2246af698cd8-3" 
      ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" 
      EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">
      MIIG....
      </o:BinarySecurityToken>
      <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-582a2846-2291-4c45-b788-2246af698cd8-1" 
      ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" 
      EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">
      MIIG....
      </o:BinarySecurityToken>
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
          <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
          <Reference URI="#_2">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>AosPkLHPJGku8gcL+toVX62fPpg=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#uuid-582a2846-2291-4c45-b788-2246af698cd8-1">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>H5fqYFR6N3ryhcna8iXirRhG6w4=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>C3oE37WKGthBLpwzN+q/qYJfMKllCnWItNInS1UY5FC4w74sZZh7OJeudS+cNciXNAvT6O+IslJAxdSwApjtuKFTtj0XzgoHqnyRoXbi8zaMT1Vinrw+QSzhhIigWlqXA+5MPUIOJWAWe2Anh6+1LtTyrJo7DpTiSvF8AkGD+sUSOiFcQ6PaA9DtaUDWUqb1rv1X3AqY4T19Twb4aT4sHc3GIi/51/3yALhY4e+jMvo9k3wreJHV/HBCK49sQUCOXHaIHdO7HFodytGRHV5qHaGiH9aJlocAqAKQuegW9O8+56AHt4v3q48zXiIrfQSnaCsSob5LQGudX1KJv7jYtQ==</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
          <o:SecurityTokenReference>
            <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-582a2846-2291-4c45-b788-2246af698cd8-3"/>
          </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body u:Id="_2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <leverAan xmlns="http://procesinfrastructuur.nl/service/aanleverservice/2007/01/">
      <betreftPI_Kenmerk xmlns=""/>
      <aanleverKenmerk xmlns="">KLogiO.OB20100305</aanleverKenmerk>
      <berichtsoort xmlns="">Omzetbelasting</berichtsoort>
      <berichtInhoud xmlns="">inhoud</berichtInhoud>
      <tijdstempelAangemaakt xmlns="">2011-06-22T15:45:18.457469+02:00</tijdstempelAangemaakt>
      <bedrijfsnummer xmlns="">24140938B01</bedrijfsnummer>
      <cspEndpoint xmlns="">http://geenausp.nl</cspEndpoint>
    </leverAan>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Capture the message by fiddler to see the whole content.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

At last I discovered why I was getting a signature over the certificate as well. It was because of the this line of code:

```
    sec.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(new X509SecurityTokenParameters());
```

Removing this line resulted in the correct message (whith only 1 reference element with then signature).

Paul